# Having problems with learning how to do combos in killer instinct 2013, with the xbox one controller

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

I understand what the instructions mean but I cant do the combos because I cant seem to get the timing right for the moves.... and such. 
Is there a trick to it, or something?, Im going through the Dojo lessons, and got stuck badly in 10 (or was it 9) with the one that has to do with starters, double autos, linkers and enders. I somehow manage to do the Starter Auto Linker Auto but then having problems with the ender, and holding the buttons not just pushing them.

And lets not even talk about starter auto linker auto shadow linker auto ender, thats just impossible.

TLDR, Having trouble doing the moves on an xbox controller, my first fighting game that I really wanna get into. (played tekken,mortal kombat, and so on before but just usually button smashed.)

Comment: I can't even do Starter Auto Linker...

Comment: Fighters like KI require frame accurate input for some moves. There is nothing to recommend besides practicing it until you can get reliable single frame timing on your moves. Other fighting games are much more forgiving in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The dojo exists for a very good reason, to practice. Don't expect to be able to get these combos on your first try, it takes a lot of time and practice, especially with later lessons (I am personally stuck on 18).

The only tip/answer I can give is the combos are very dependent on timing, and inputs are kind of buffered.

So you have to do your opener, then wait for the opener to be near completed. Press the auto-double button as shown (press or hold), and then go straight into the next part it asks (linker or ender). Button mashing and twirling the stick hoping for the best won't get you anywhere.

If the controller itself is giving you trouble, try remapping the controls.

Take your time and be deliberate. You can even set up your options to show the inputs you are doing on screen to help.

Unfortunately the Dojo lessons are all done with Jago. Other characters (Sabrewulf and Riptor to be exact) are much easier to learn on.